# Titanium xhr events not firing

Tags: iphone, xmlhttprequest, titanium, appcelerator

I have been trying to get a simple xhr request to work but for some unknown reasons nothing happens, not even the onerror function fires off.

```
        var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        Titanium.API.log('Success');
    }
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        Titanium.API.log('Error');
    }

    xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com/");
    xhr.send();
```

I have tried this with a new created project and still no luck. Using little snitch I noticed that a connection is made by the app to the given url ... but still nothing fires off.

What am I missing?

Also I'm developing on an iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the XHR request - the Titanium.API.log function takes two arguments, but you're only giving it one, so it's probably just not printing to the console. The Titanium documentation is down at the moment so I can't link you to the correct API, but if you change your code to use Ti.API.info, for example, you should see something printed. This works for me:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function() {
    Titanium.API.info('Success');
}
xhr.onerror = function() {
    Titanium.API.info('Error');
}

xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com/");
xhr.send();
```

Comment: That is a weird one. You can call log with just one argument with no errors. What I did notice was that if you experience what I'm having, its because there is an error within the xhr. Such errors do not appear in the debug console ... its just crashes silently ... so I stripped everything back to basics and now it works fine.

Comment: The only reason I spotted it was because I was testing out the 1.8 beta - the V8 engine is a lot more strict with syntax, so I got an error.